# Debugging RoR Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going through a tutorial and just came up with this error statement when trying to add a user to my db.  I'm trying to figure out how to properly read these error statements.  For instance I see that the output says syntax error, unexpected tASSOC. expecting keyword_end.  So to try to fix that before posting here, I commented out the line in my user.rb file (the one the statement is pointing too).  But that did not work.  I also put in an extra "end" since the terminal output said "expecting keyword_end."

**Here is the exact terminal output:**

```
   SyntaxError: /Users/zkidd/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
            :length => { :maximum => 50 }
                      ^
/Users/zkidd/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting $end
            :format => { :with => email_regex },
                      ^
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `block in load_file'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
 from (irb):6
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
 from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**And here is my user.rb file:**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true
            :length => { :maximum => 50 }

  validates :email, :presence => true
            :format => { :with => email_regex },
            :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, as I really don't want to rebuild this thing from the beginning :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the :presence => true parameters:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true,
            :length => { :maximum => 50 }

  validates :email, :presense => true,
            :format => { :with => email_regex },
            :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

Comment: Thank you Pan. . . I also realized that I misspelled presence in the second validator statement.  All fixed now.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, i too had some missing commas, spelling mistakes and extra colon. The error in cmd prompt is kind of congested and takes your attention to thinking rails will be the culprit, but instead it was typos. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing commas on the 2 lines preceding the syntax errors.